# Detect position of loading Javascript libraries in Joomla frontend?

Tags: joomla-3.x, javascript, smartsearch, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a way to detect position of loading javascript libraries in Joomla(my goal is 'framework.bootstrap'). because I currently follow this [post](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4953/how-can-i-completely-remove-bootstrap-from-the-frontend-of-joomla)
but after using "unset" method from `[JDataset][2]` method collections, the boostrap framework is completely disabled in all Joomla web pages except in

> com_finder

component. How can I detect where this library is added with non-standard way because unset method doesn't affect on this component.
also:
1) I moved unset method before and after `<jdoc:include type="head" />` line, there is no effect
2) use plugin onAfterRender solution to call unset method but no effect again
3) and completely check all codes in com_finder and its dependencies e.g: filters, in admin and site part to find 'framework.bootstrap' in them but I found anything unless in admin part that is not effective for my frontend !!!

Do you have other or better solution for me

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean:`JHTML::_('bootstrap.framework')`

If you want to disable bootstrap anywhere except back-end. Add this:

```
if( JFactory::getApplication()->isSite() ) return;
```

at the begining of function `framework` in file: `/libraries/cms/html/bootstrap.php`. This is not best solution but will work for any extension that use JHTML for loading boostrap (well almost all of them do).

#### Tracking where bootstrap has been included

You can use my solution to track all places where this function was called. Just create global array and put there data from `debug_backtrace()` called inside `/libraries/cms/html/bootstrap.php`. This will give you complete call chain for each bootstrap include. At the end of system execution (so probably in template) you can print that array.

Comment: You're right, this is one solution but you know this is non-maintainability for developing in future. Does anyone have another suggestion? I'll try to find a solution which use Joomla template overriding to this change

Comment: I added description how to use my solution to track bootstrap include event