# Unset Unwanted Backend CSS and Javascripts

Tags: joomla-3.x, administrator, k2

I'm creating a modification of K2 module and I want to remove some unnecesary K2 css and script load.

I have tried to use

```
unset($this->_scripts['']);
unset($this->_styleSheets['']);
```

but return an error message :

> Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property JFormFieldK2Mods::$_scripts has no effect in /Applications/Ampps/www/j39/modules/mod_k2mods/admin/elements/k2mods.php on line 18

How can I unset unnecesary css and script load properly?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that a component overrides the template files as you discovered.

So - your solutioncould be:

a) custom plugin development to remove said files. Here's a discussion: [How can I completely remove Bootstrap from the frontend of Joomla?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4953/how-can-i-completely-remove-bootstrap-from-the-frontend-of-joomla)

b) Modify the jdoc:include type=head in your Joomla Template:

- https://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/joomla/36-customize-the-jdoc-include-type-head-part.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29145806/edit-the-output-of-jdocinclude-type-head-via-renderer-head-php-alter

c) I use **[JCC - JS CSS Control](https://joomla-extensions.kubik-rubik.de/jcc-js-css-control)** plugin - which is the most reliable and simplest way I have found.

I encounter the issue with flexiContent + RSform - so keep my own adaptation:

https://gist.github.com/iamrobert/a1316f598a1acc745fec8cc81d866044

---

As you're seeking the administrator - I would search the module folder for the line of code and comment it out.

As I don't use K2, I looked at the mod_k2_Stats and found the following in the tmpl folder - so it could be removed:

```
if (K2_JVERSION == '30') {
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addStyleDeclaration('
    dl.tabs {float:left;margin:10px 0 -1px 0;z-index:50;}
    dl.tabs dt {float:left;padding:4px 10px;border:1px solid #ccc;margin-left:3px;background:#e9e9e9;color:#666;}
    dl.tabs dt.open {background:#f9f9f9;border-bottom:1px solid #f9f9f9;z-index:100;color:#000;}
    div.current {clear:both;border:1px solid #ccc;padding:10px 10px;background:#f9f9f9;}
    dl.tabs h3 {font-size:12px;line-height:12px;margin:4px;}
');
}
```

Or in mod_k2_quick_icons:

```
K2HelperHTML::loadHeadIncludes(true, false, true, false);
if ($modCSSStyling) {
    $document->addStyleSheet(JURI::base(true).'/modules/'.$mod_name.'/tmpl/css/style.css?v='.K2_CURRENT_VERSION);
}
```

Or in other non k2 modules:

```
$url = 'modules/mod_adminmenumanager/javascript/responsive.js';
$document->addScript($url);
```

or

```
echo "<script>window.parent.addtomenu_setMessage( '" . JText::_('COM_MENUS_MENU_ITEM_SAVE_SUCCESS', true) . "', 1 );</script>\n";
```

Comment: hi @iamrobert, thanks for your answer, but I was talking about backend (administrator page) not frontend

Comment: JCC - JS CSS Control - does have backend removal access:
https://i.imgur.com/SXya8vK.png

Comment: Hi - I updated my answer.